# В HTML переместить DIV на верх списка?

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли через чистый JS перкместить DIV на верх списка, вот пример:

```
<div id="main">
     <div id="one">Первый блок</div>
     <div id="two">Второй блок</div>
     <div id="three">Третий блок</div>
</div>
```

Но третий блок **id="three"** - должен быть на верху, если нажать кнопку

Вывод должен быть таким:

```
Третий блок
Первый блок
Второй блок
```

Возможно ли такое реализовать?

Comment: `main.prepend(three);`

Comment: @Deonis , большое вам спасибо! Это решило моб проблему =)